# Is JS input spinners exists? NO JQUERY

Tags: javascript, input, spinner

I'm looking for js spinners as on picture below (left & right control keys).
But i don't want to use jquery in my project. If you have any snippets, useful links - please paste it here. :) Simple short code is preferred.. :) 
Maybe it has another name (not spinner, but.. ?)?

[image]

Comment: Just attach click event handlers to the plus and minus button where one increments the value and the other decrements.

Comment: Thank you for answer. You advice to use 2 simple buttons, input field and MutationObserver? Right? :)

Comment: @sameuser Why `MutationObserver`? Just add click events to the buttons.

Comment: Ok, will try. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function addSpinner(parent){
var very = document.createElement("div"); // create a div
var minus = document.createElement("button"); // create minus button
var plus = document.createElement("button"); // create plus button
minus.innerHTML = "-"; // draw minus sign
plus.innerHTML = "+"; // draw plus sign
var input = document.createElement("input"); // create an input
input.type = "number"; // type number
input.value = "0"; // and default is 0
very.appendChild(minus); // append the minus sign to the div
very.appendChild(input); // append the input to the div
very.appendChild(plus); // append the plus sign to the div
minus.addEventListener("click", function() {input.value = +input.value - 1});
plus.addEventListener("click", function() {input.value = +input.value + 1});
// + before input.value is to change type from string to number so we can increase/decrease number by 1
parent.appendChild(very);
}
```

Now you call it: `addSpinner(document.body)`